# SwiftUI clipped image still accepts tap gesture

Tags: image, swiftui, aspect-ratio, aspect, clipped

I have trouble clipping the image in SwiftUI

Here is the code with minimal wrong-working example:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("iPhone13Pro")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
            .border(.black)
            .clipped()
            .onTapGesture {
                print("click")
            }
    }
}
```

As I expect, a tap outside the frame should print nothing to the console, but it prints

As a result, the image is not getting clipped, and I am seeing the `click` in the console

The result seems to be rendered right, but the touch outside the image (red arrows) still produces the console log

[image: With .clipped()]

The image is not square, that is more horizontal, so, without `.clipped()` that looks like this:

[image: No .clipped()]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out the answer

`.clipped()` is responsible only for the visual representation of the view

To actually restrict the view by the frame and prevent it to cross the border, use `.contentShape(_:)`

That solves the problem for me

Comment: Nice work. I actually didn't know that so will make sure to use it in the future 

Comment: note: `.contentShape(Rectangle())`, for example, should be used just after `.clipped()` modifier

Comment: Actually even after setting `contentShape` the image still is on top of other views on the screen and prevents them from being tapped. So neither image nor other views under its clipped sides can be tapped if you tap not in the specified `contentShape`